# GCP external IP range

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am starting up a vps hosting company which i am planning to migrate to google cloud. The current issue i have is that each vps created must use an IP from a block which i have to assign to the server in advance. I have searched for information in external IP ranges on google and also in the knowledgebase and can't seem to find how to do this. I have setup an instance using two VPCs, however client vps won't recognized eth1 as an extra IP. Can someone point me to any information that can solve this?

Comment: 1) You must allocate IP addresses one at a time. You cannot allocate an IP block. 2) Addresses are no longer free. An unused IP address will cost $7.20 per month. An assigned address will cost $2.88 per month. 3) Carefully review pricing while designing your systems. 4) If you have a large customer base speak to Google sales. https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the static external IP. These IPs remain static and you can know before creating VM.
Ref: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

Also, if you already have some public IPs with you, then BYOIP can be a solution here https://cloud.google.com/solutions/custom-public-ip-addresses-on-compute-engine

Answer (score 1):

The following page seems to shed some light on how to get the IP Address range you are after:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#where_can_i_find_product_name_short_ip_ranges

The only other way to get around the issue is:

1. you reserve some ip addresses in Google Cloud, as long as they are in use you don't charged
2. You can bring your own IP Addresses
   https://cloud.google.com/solutions/custom-public-ip-addresses-on-compute-engine

Hope this helps.

Comment: Google Static IP addresses are `no longer free` starting January 1, 2020. This includes assigned (and in use) addresses. https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing